# iPhone : Leave API changing pages

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I was wondering how can I change the pages of  a PDF file via code on[leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) api ?

```
 [self displayPageNumber: 1];
```

but just change the the title and this code :

```
- (void) renderPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, index + 1);
    CGAffineTransform transform = aspectFit(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox),
                                            CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);
}
```

If I change the 1 number it changes but does not work with external button and number for example

```
int myNumber = 1;
```

and then change 1 to

```
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, index + myNumber);
```

and then :

```
 button {

myNumber = 4;

}
```

nothing happens !!!

Comment: is there someone help me please :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simple function in this API which you can use it :

`leavesView.currentPageIndex = 20`;

and use this for title :

```
[self displayPageNumber:20];
```

good luck !